# pyro: how to specify conditional distribution

Tags: pytorch, pyro.ai

I am trying to use pyro for specifying a Bayesian network. I have a child node `D` which is continuous and it has three discrete nodes are parents, each with 10 possible states:

So, I first define my discrete nodes as:

```
import torch
import pyro
import pyro.distributions as dist

def model(data):
    A = pyro.sample("A", dist.Dirichlet(torch.ones(10)))
    B = pyro.sample("B", dist.Dirichlet(torch.ones(10)))
    C = pyro.sample("C", dist.Dirichlet(torch.ones(10)))
```

Now, as I understand I need to define `P(D|A, B, C)`. I want to model this as a normal distribution but not sure how to do this conditioning. My plan is to put priors on this distribution parameters and then use MCMC or HMC to estimate the posterior distribution and learn the model parameters.

However, not sure how to proceed with the model definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good thing about `pyro` is that the model definition is very pythonic. The underlying PyTorch machinery can track dependencies for you.

All you need is use the samples `A`, `B` and `C` and compute the parameters of the conditional `p(D|A,B,C)`

```
def cond_mean(a, b, c):
    return # use a,b,c to compute mean

def cond_scale(a, b, c):
    return # use a,b,c to compute scale

def model(data):
    A = pyro.sample("A", dist.Dirichlet(torch.ones(10)))
    B = pyro.sample("B", dist.Dirichlet(torch.ones(10)))
    C = pyro.sample("C", dist.Dirichlet(torch.ones(10)))

    D = pyro.sample("D", dist.Normal(loc=cond_mean(A, B, C), scale=cond_scale(A, B, C)
    ...
```

Comment: Oh wow, this is really awesome. Could I ask a follow up question...this is more about modeling in general...How does one usually go about modeling such a conditional distribution? What I mean is what would these look like...For example, in this case considering that my parent nodes are discrete, should one just get some estimate it from the training data. So, I would have combinations like:

```
if a== 0 and b == 1 and c== 2:
    return something
elif ...
   return something
```

How would one compute this if one of the parents was a continuous node?

Comment: This is a broad question and require knowledge of your whole model, data and your end goal. Feel free to post your elaborate question on ai.stackexchange.com

Comment: I added the question here: https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/31953/specifying-a-hybrid-bayesian-network-in-pyro

There was no tag for pyro unfortunately